# Generic Typing for function parameters

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to understand something that looks obvious to me, but which doesn't seems to be allowed by Typescript with all strict flags on (surely for very good reasons). Let my show you:

We All know that:

```
export interface Basic {
  value: "foo" | "bar" | "baz";
}

export interface Constraint extends Basic {
  value: "foo";
}
```

Works. But more surprisingly (to me at least):

```
export interface WithFunctionsBasic {
  value: (t: "foo" | "bar" | "baz") => void;
}

export interface WithFunctionsConstraint extends WithFunctionsBasic { // WithFunctionsConstraint extends incorrectly WithFunctionsBasic
  value: (t: "foo") => void;
}
```

Doesn't.

We can make it Generic to allow us that kind of behavior like:

```
export interface WithFunctionsParametric<T extends Basic> {
  value: (t: T["value"]) => void;
}

const variableConstraint: WithFunctionsParametric<Constraint> = { value: (t: "foo") => {} };
const variableBasic: WithFunctionsParametric<Basic> = { value: (t: "foo" | "bar" | "baz") => {} };
```

And both works. But it gets a little tricky because despite Constraint extending Basic:

```
const variableConstraint: WithFunctionsParametric<Constraint> = { value: (t: "foo") => {} };
const variableBasic: WithFunctionsParametric<Basic> = variableConstraint; // Not Working
```

To my understanding, if Constraint extends Basic (and this is the case), the latter should be working. Can somebody explain me why please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem fundamentally stems from an important distinction between how inputs and outputs behave in terms of inheritance.

Let's look at the first example:

```js
export interface Basic {
  value: "foo" | "bar" | "baz";
}

export interface Constraint extends Basic {
  value: "foo";
}
```

Here, `Constraint` extends `Basic`. Both have the property `value`, but they disagree about its type.

- `Basic` says that it has to be either `"foo"`, `"bar"` or `"baz"`. Fair enough.
- `Constraint` says that it can only be `"foo"`. This is compatible since it's a subset of `Basic`'s set of valid values.

In other words, an instance of `Constraint` does not break the promises that `Basic` makes. `value` is still always one of `"foo"`, `"bar"` or `"baz"`. The fact that `Constraint` will only ever output a single one is irrelevant; it still keeps the promise that the returned value is from that set of three values.

Now, let's look at the second example:

```js
export interface WithFunctionsBasic {
  value: (t: "foo" | "bar" | "baz") => void;
}

export interface WithFunctionsConstraint extends WithFunctionsBasic { // WithFunctionsConstraint extends incorrectly WithFunctionsBasic
  value: (t: "foo") => void;
}
```

Now, what does this mean? Well, `WithFunctionsBasic` makes a promise: "I have a function called `value` that accepts a `"foo"`, a `"bar"` or a `"baz"`".

Now, `WithFunctionsConstraint` extends `WithFunctionsBasic`, meaning it has to keep the same promises that `WithFunctionsBasic` makes. Well, does it?

No, it does not. Its `value` function only accepts a `"foo"`. In other words, we're trying to create a `WithFunctionsBasic` subtype that breaks the contract of what it means to be a `WithFunctionsBasic`, since its `value` function cannot accept `"bar"` or `"baz"`.

When it comes to *outputs*, a subtype must have *the same or stronger restrictions*. Further limiting the types of the output doesn't break the promises of the supertype. In formal terms, return types are *covariant*; they are allowed to become more specific through inheritance.

On the other hand, when it comes to *inputs*, a subtype must have *the same or weaker restrictions*. That is, it must accept at least the same inputs (to adhere to the promise), but may also allow additional types not permitted by the supertype. In formal terms, function arguments are *contravariant*; they are allowed to become less specific through inheritance.

Having `WithFunctionsConstraint` only accept `"foo"` is invalid since that means that a `WithFunctionsConstraint` isn't a valid `WithFunctionsBasic`. However, having it accept `"foo"`, `"bar"`, `"baz"`, `"lol"` and `"wut"` is perfectly valid.

The rest of the issues you're facing in the question all seem to be different variations of the same fundamental problem.

Answer (score 0):

the difference is what you extend. In your first example, it is pretty clear, your `interface Basic` with a `value` property that is one of the following `"foo" | "bar" | "baz"`.
Your overwrite `Constraint` still matches this interface since `foo` is part of the above type.

Now let's look at your second example. `value: (t: "foo" | "bar" | "baz") => void;` works different than you expect. Because you are defining it as one function that has one of those 3 parameters. And so your extended class does not match this selector anymore, because the function definitions do not match. `value: (t: "foo") => void;` is not part of `value: (t: "foo" | "bar" | "baz") => void;`

If you actually want to split up like you suggest you have to do it like this, split up the basic function into separate function calls with one type each

```js
export interface WithFunctionsBasic {
  value: ((t: "foo") => void) | ((t: "bar") => void) | ((t: "baz") => void);
}

export interface WithFunctionsConstraint extends WithFunctionsBasic {
  value: (t: "foo") => void;
}
```